# How to create Meteor Mongo validation object operators?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

While trying to update a Meteor/MongoDB record I'm getting an error that I can't really put in place. Here's my attempt at `.update` and the resulting error message:

```
> Profiles.update(currentProfile()._id, {latlng: latlng})
```

`Error: When the modifier option is true, validation object must have at least one operator`

What is this validation object and how can I give it at least one operator?

If I use the `$set` operator it doesn't actually do anything:

```
Profiles.update(currentProfile()._id, {$set: {latlng: latlng}})

Profiles.find(currentProfile()._id).fetch()
[ 
_id: "wuzriXfcS2PxBmwcE"
email: "kasper.souren@example.com"
github: "guaka"
name: "Kasper"
twitter: "guaka"
userId: "G4gNTtwQj6rSkwyob"
__proto__: Object
]
```

(note there's no latlng)

Comment: Have you tried grabbing the actual value of `_id` and using that instead of grabbing it off of `currentProfile`?

Comment: What do you mean by that? How would `currentProfile()._id` not be the actual value?

Comment: Does the value appear in the actual database? Is is possible that `latlng` is not being published due to a `fields` option on the server?

Comment: I get this error when using SimpleSchema, maybe it's related to that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use the `$set`-operator:

```
Profiles.update(currentProfile()._id, {$set: {latlng: latlng}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
Profiles.update({_id: currentProfile()._id}, {$set: {latlng: latlng}})
```